# Upload KMZ file into My Google Map with images in Placemark description

Tags: image, google-maps, upload, kml, kmz

I am creating a .KMZ file that could be imported to My Google Maps, and I want to use images in description of some Placemarks. KMZ format is just a zipped folder containing KML file with the stucture and then the image files. The problem is I don't know if/how I can link the image files in KML for Google to parse them and use them. Currently my structure is something like this:

```
main.kmz
    -main.kml
    -image.jpg
```

and in main.kmz I link to my image as

```
<Placemark>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>
         <![CDATA[<img src="image.jpg" width='600' />]]>
    </description>
    <Point><coordinates>153.4380409849745,-28.07224651054966,10.2340928109942</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

But this doesn't work, My Maps don't process the image and all I get is a black rectangle. Strangely enough, if I import the same file to Google Earth Desktop app, the file gets uploaded and processed correctly and shows up.

When I upload the image manually through My Maps interface, it shows up correctly and if I then export the layer as KMZ, I see their image is linked as

```
  <description><![CDATA[<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/cbMcdkW0FH86QPYuJH_hOBeH0dMgcgevmf9l37Lk5O2Ap0r_gTrZyuREZumY11XW2E3I0r7hpHOpGlCSVG6jMJJFVFbTpxCw71hZORu8YRtyPdv0nRGprLkMefNBCNj4wpHi" height="200" width="auto" />]]></description>
```

And this shows up correctly. So ideally this is what I want to end up with, but I am not sure if there is any way to let Google know about the image when importing so it stores it in a similar way as when uploading manually and then links it in image description.

Answer (score 1):

When you include an image in a KMZ file, and open it in Earth or Maps, it does not "upload" it to a hosting server, but rather uses it locally in the viewer, directly out of the KMZ.  MyMaps can't do that, and needs images hosted online somewhere. As you saw, when you add an image manually, MyMaps will upload it to a hosting server, but does not do that for images embedded in a KMZ that's imported, which is why it's not working for you.

Your KMZ should work in the Google Maps API, if you want to use that to display it.  Or you can upload images to public hosting somewhere, and add them via public URLs in the balloons in your KMZ.